# Why the border-color changing every time I type something

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I created todo app in `react` with `styled-components`. I added a functionality of changing **border-color** randomly with that I mean every time user added a todo it will select any random hex code from given array i.e `colors` in my case and append it in border-color of the same. I achieved that but with that I created a bug so every time I type something in input field the `border-color` changing on its own. I don't know what actually causing this. Providing my entire code.

**COMPLETE CODE**

```js
import {
    StyledTodo,
    StyledTodoDate,
    StyledTodoItem,
    StyledButtonGroup,
    StyledTodoButton,
} from './Todo.element';


const StyledTodo = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    border-left: 0.5rem solid ${(props) => props.randomColor};

    &:not(:last-of-type) {
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
    }
`;

function Todo({ text, todo, todos, setTodos }) {
    const colors = ['#32ADE6', '#5856D6', '#00C7BE', '#FF9500', '#FF2D55', '#30B0C7', '#FFCC00'];

    function deleteTodoHandler() {
        setTodos(todos.filter((element) => element.id !== todo.id));
    }

    function completeTodoHandler() {
        setTodos(
            todos.map((item) => {
                if (item.id === todo.id) {
                    return {
                        ...item,
                        completed: !item.completed,
                    };
                }

                return item;
            })
        );
    }

    return (
        <StyledTodo randomColor={colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]}>
            <StyledTodoItem className={todo.completed ? 'completed' : ''}>
                {text}
                <StyledTodoDate>
                    <span>
                        Last Modified :&nbsp;
                        {new Date(todo.lastModified).toLocaleDateString('en-IN', {
                            hour: '2-digit',
                            minute: '2-digit',
                        })}
                    </span>
                </StyledTodoDate>
            </StyledTodoItem>

            <StyledButtonGroup>
                <StyledTodoButton
                    className={todo.completed ? 'undo' : 'complete'}
                    onClick={completeTodoHandler}
                >
                    {todo.completed ? (
                        <svg width="24px" height="24px" fill="#a2845e" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" />
                            <path d="M12.5 8c-2.65 0-5.05.99-6.9 2.6L2 7v9h9l-3.62-3.62c1.39-1.16 3.16-1.88 5.12-1.88 3.54 0 6.55 2.31 7.6 5.5l2.37-.78C21.08 11.03 17.15 8 12.5 8z" />
                        </svg>
                    ) : (
                        <svg width="24px" height="24px" fill="#34c759" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" />
                            <path d="M9 16.17L4.83 12l-1.42 1.41L9 19 21 7l-1.41-1.41L9 16.17z" />
                        </svg>
                    )}
                </StyledTodoButton>

                <StyledTodoButton className="delete" onClick={deleteTodoHandler}>
                    <svg width="24px" height="24px" fill="#ff3b30" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" />
                        <path d="M6 19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7H6v12zM8 9h8v10H8V9zm7.5-5l-1-1h-5l-1 1H5v2h14V4h-3.5z" />
                    </svg>
                </StyledTodoButton>
            </StyledButtonGroup>
        </StyledTodo>
    );
}

export default Todo;
```

Comment: Is it because you have `randomColor={colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)}`? Maybe you need to make the random color a memo. `const randomColor = useMemo(() => colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length), [])`

Comment: @Acidic9 It worked!! Thanks . Can you tell me what causing this problem??

Comment: React components rerender whenever any state/props change. Putting it in a `useMemo(fn, [])` ensures that the variable is only created once on render

Comment: @Acidic9 Now I got it but there is something; whenever I am reloading the page the ```color``` is changing again! On every reload I am seeing a different color! I want after setting a color it should not be change.

Comment: It naturally changes because on reload the memoized function will be called again for the first time. If you want to persist the state of your application over reloads, you would have to save the selected color somewhere, maybe in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

Comment: As @Gh05d said, reloading the page re-executes your javascript again. Nothing persists unless you use the mechanisms Gh05d descibed (localStorage, sessionStorage, etc).

Comment: @Gh05d Although I am saving all todos in ```localstorage``` but wondering how to save the ```border-color``` key-value pair 

Comment: Do something like `const selectedColor = await localStorage.getItem("selectedColor")` and check for it. If it exists, only take the variable, otherwise do your random logic.